# Formula to calculate percentage from two columns

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write a formula that returns a percentage. Let's say I have columns A, B, C. If A = 4 and B = 5, it should give 80% in the same row in column C (which is the result column).

Some more examples of how it should be: if A = 9, B = 10, it will automatically fill C with 90% in the same row.

A and B are already filled out with values, so all that is left is to fill column C with percentage as described above for each row automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentage is just a way of *formatting* the result of *dividing* two numbers. So, what you should do is (a) divide the values in A by the values in B; (b) format the result is a percentage.

Division can be done with the formula (for cell C2):

```
=arrayformula(iferror(A2:A/B2:B))
```

which works for all rows starting from the 2nd (assuming 1st row is headers). The `iferror` wrapper leaves the result empty if the division could not be done (e.g., for the empty rows in the sheet).

To format a column as a percentage, select it and click the button with % symbol.